# Why is there a black box under my navigation bar when resizing to a smaller title? Swift 5

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my app, there is a main screen where there is a large title in the navigation bar. There is also a detail screen where there is a small title (following Apple's HIG).

However, when transitioning to the detail screen, during the animation, there is a black box underneath the navigation bar (see image)

[image]

I have

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

too which doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I just fixed it.

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = .white
```